# TimescaleDB to handle complex join

Tags: postgresql, left-join, hypertable, timescaledb

I'm using Postgres 11 with timescaleDB in a LINUX machine(16 cores and 32 RAM). I have following 2 tables and only one is the time column.

1. usersTransations (time timestamp without time zone, userId String, locationID string)
2. location (locationID string, longitude double, latitude double )

This `usersTransations` is a hypertable with 24 Chunks which has created for 1 hour interval. and location is a Postgres table. I have created index on locationID (with time column). `usersTransations` table is very large about 1 billion records. I used following query to join above 2 tables but it take a very large time.

```
SELECT *
FROM usersTransations
LEFT JOIN location ON location."locationID"= usersTransations."locationID"
```

Is there any way to optimise join queries in TimescaleDB?

Comment: what's your definition of a "very large time" - (it IS a billion records)

Comment: It took around 10 - 20 minutes

Comment: What version of TimescaleDB?

Comment: Please clarify via edits not comments. Please give as much as possible of a [mcve].